# Copy and create list items with multiple properties using arrays

Tags: 2010, javascript

I'm trying to copy multiple field values from a record (selected items only), push it into an array and write it to another list record using the values from the array. I'm having an issue packing the multiple properties into the array and unpacking the values on the other side. I've successfully done this with one field value, but not multiples.

I can successfully see the values in my console from the first array(items), but after that I'm getting undefined. Is there a better way to do this?

See code below...

```
 //Get selected items from view
function getSelected() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName2);
    var SelectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var items = [];
    for (var i in SelectedItems) {
        var id = SelectedItems[i].id;
        var item = targetList.getItemById(id);
        clientContext.load(item, "A_x0020_State", "A_x0020_Name");
        items.push(item);
    } // End for
}
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function() {
                var results = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    var items.Aname = item.get_item('A_x0020_Name');
                    var items.Astate = item.get_item('A_x0020_State');
                    results.push(items);
                    console.log(items.Aname, items.Astate);
                } //End for
            }, failure); //End ClientContext
            writeSelected(results);
} 

 function writeSelected(results) {
    for (var k in results) {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName4);
        var item = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);
        oListItem.set_item("Link_x0020_ID", fieldValue);
        oListItem.set_item("A_x0020_Name", ???);
        oListItem.set_item("A_x0020_State", ???);
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failure)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in javascript instead of C# or PowerShell?

Comment: No access to server side...